# How to pass value/ parameter at the time of initialization of react app from asp.net core middleware?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core

I want to fetch a value from 3rd party API in the middleware (startup) and pass this value to my react app before it display. How can I achieve this? I am quite naive, so any guidance is much appreciated.

I actually want to retrieve language code of user and at the time of loading application (react/typescript). Application should take that language code and display the labels accordingly. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you post some code about where the value actually located in the startup? Most values in startup are in appsettings. Do you need some guide to expose this value to an api, so your reacjs can fetch it?

Comment: @Jerry Yes, I need some guidance on how to fetch that value in react. I want to add something after authorization in ASP.net core Configure method in startup.cs file 

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

Here I want to fetch data from a 3rd party API and pass this to react file before the UI is displayed. I actually, want to set the language code (localization) which is actually not a part of claims.

React/TS file : I want to access that language code here

export function createApp(
  appConfig: AppConfig,  
  titleService?: TitleService
): Application {
}

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you want to use asp.net core to fetch data from 3rd party api after authorization to get "language code".
Then you want this asp.net core application to make a new api to send the "language code" to front-end react application.
And this "language code" should be fetch by react before render.

1.If you want to do something after authorization. Codes are not write in the "startup.cs" or "program.cs".  "app.useAuthentication" or "app.useAuthorization" just mean a processing pipeline in asp.net core.

You only need to add a `[Authorize]`attribute on the top of the new api controller to make this api work after authorization.
To make a new api in asp.net core, you can create a "Controllers" folder and right click the folder to add empty controller.
[image] 
Then you can write some codes like below:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;

namespace WebApplication63.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class NewAPIController : ControllerBase
    {
        public async Task<string> GetLanguage()
        {
            var client= new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://{3rd party api}");
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var language = content.languagecode;   //parse the content and convert to your demand.
            return language;
        }
    }
}
```

Then this new api will return "language" with the url"https://{core app domain}/api/newapi"

Then in react fetch the new api in the component before-render event
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-lifecycle-components/

```
componentWillMount() 
    { 
        fetch("https://{core app domain}/api/newapi")
                    .then(res=> language)
    }
```